# Windows 8: Set default email address when invoking Share charm's mail feature

Tags: windows-store-apps

I need to set a default email address when invoking the Share charm's mail feature.
Specifically, I already know the recipient's email address.

As a result, I want to populate the mailto address with this data instead of forcing the user to insert this data manually.

Any suggestions?

```
    public void OnHtmlRequested(DataRequestedEventArgs args, string title, string html)
    {
        args.Request.Data.Properties.Title = title;
        args.Request.Data.Properties.Description = "my description";

        args.Request.Data.SetHtmlFormat(HtmlFormatHelper.CreateHtmlFormat(html));
    }
```

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but I'm having the same issue now. Did you have any luck with this?